# Return correct currency for Intl.NumberFormat Romanian lei

Tags: javascript, intl

I'm trying to format a number and display it as price in Romanian lei.

This is my snippet:

```js
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('ro-RO', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RON',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
}).format(123));
```

I am expecting it to show `123 lei` or at least `123L` (as per wikipedia) but instead I sea `123 RON` which is the currency code but not the symbol.

Is there a way to display "**lei**" using the native api at all?

Comment: I can't spot anything that's obviously wrong in your code. I guess the database in the browser's runtime doesn't have the symbol available for that combination of currency and locale. (Or perhaps an abbreviation doesn't count as symbol.)

Comment: Yeah, most likely the first since it's not even returning `L` which is the symbol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_leu

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, by replacing the `românești` part.

```js
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('ro-RO', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RON',
    currencyDisplay: 'name',
  }).format(123).replace('românești', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolae! I was hoping I could avoid making an exception since this is actually a helper function that receives price, locale and currency code as arguments and always returns the symbols. It has been working well for all other countries returning correct symbols but with Romania it's not the case. I guess I will have to override the native localisation for some currencies :(

Comment: No worries, good luck with your project. I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'name' for currencyDisplay, and it will show up as `123,00 lei romanesti`, after which you could just trim the `romanesti` part.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use it like this:

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat('ro-RO', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'lei'
}).format(123);
```